# How to clear HTML5 Canvas with Transparent White?

Tags: html5-canvas, webgl, babylonjs

I've searched all over the place and can't seem to find the answer to this.

I'm trying to draw white text with white antialiasing.

I've tried these two:

1. fillRect with rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) <- this seems to not do anything, still black AA
2. fillRect with rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.01) <- gives white AA, but not completely transparent

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: White text with white antialiasing? What does that even mean? The two ways to make antialiased text is sub-pixel rendering (offset of r g and b channels) or transparency. And yes, transparent pixels are all converted to transparent-black in a canvas.

Comment: @Kaiido The pixels are aliased between the transparent-black and solid-white text, causing visual artifacts in the aliasing, Example: rendering white text on a black-transparent canvas, on a white background HTML page, you can see the text outline due to aliasing solid-white with transparent-black. What I want is white-solid to white-transparent aliasing.

Comment: So you are saying that [in this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ax9k8vbj/) you see artifacts? That would be a browser bug.

Comment: @Kaiido Ok, this is a bit more tricky than I thought. I'm using BabylonJS which uses HTML canvas under the hood for text rendering.  Since the texture is ultimately rendered with WebGL, it is linear blending the aliased white pixels with the black-transparent pixels next to them.

See http://pasteall.org/media/8/f/8f4ec476e7267b529b8c1fe3c8e60c3d.png

What I need is to clear the canvas with white-transparent so that the pixels next to the aliased white pixels are white-transparent.

Comment: So this becomes a [webgl] problem. Show your code if you want help.

Comment: Well, it wouldn't be a WebGL problem if the texture was white.  If you right-click -> Save image on the fiddle you shared, open it in GIMP and deselect the alpha channel, you can see all the black pixels surrounding the A.  I'm actually not sure what kind of blending Canvas uses when you zoom in with the browser, they must be doing something special to not blend between white and black... But I was able to solve for my case by only using the alpha channel from canvas, and coloring it separately.

Comment: Well I'm sorry but even when using that canvas as a texture to a webgl canvas (in which I'm really not proficient at all), I still [can't reproduce](https://jsfiddle.net/s5nj8vhf/). What about you finally provide some code so we can help you?

Comment: Would have to call `gl.enable(gl.BLEND); gl.blendFunc(gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);` before `gl.drawElements` to show transparency.  I added those but it's showing jagged edges, so there's something else missing.  Here is a playground showing what I was running into: https://playground.babylonjs.com/#TMHF80#356

Comment: Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6p8xr1mc/) that does what I want.  Only had to add 3 lines (search for "// NEW").  So I guess this is more of a BabylonJS question than WebGL now?

Comment: It was something BabylonJS was doing for some reason.  I posted here: https://forum.babylonjs.com/t/light-colored-text-with-alpha-aliasing-artifacts/17525